# Lasso Regression - Coding Issue and Seeking Assistance with syntax

Tags: machine-learning, new-operator, helper, lasso-regression

I was trying to do Lasso regression using the following code from this page 
https://www.rstatisticsblog.com/data-science-in-action/lasso-regression/

The problem is that my r doesn't recognize y-var[test] saying it isn't found. When I convert that to y-var[x-test] which it does take, I then get the following message after this line of code

```py
cv_output <- cv.glmnet(x_vars[train,], y_var[train], 
            alpha = 1, lambda = lambda_seq)

Error in storage.mode(y) <- "double" : 
  invalid to change the storage mode of a factor
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Does my post answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are some typos/bugs in the code you are referring to. I fixed some of them, and this is what works for me:

```
library(glmnet)

# Loading the data
data(swiss)

x_vars <- model.matrix(Fertility~. , swiss)[,-1]
y_var <- swiss$Fertility
lambda_seq <- 10^seq(2, -2, by = -.1)

set.seed(86)
train <- sample(1:nrow(x_vars), floor(nrow(x_vars)/2))

cv_output <- cv.glmnet(x_vars[train,], y_var[train], 
                       alpha = 1, lambda = lambda_seq)
```

I am only getting a warning about `grouped=FALSE`.